# How does maven get JAR files?

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I read that if we include the dependencies in `pom.xml,` Maven gets all the required JARs to compile a program?

Or am i wrong? Do we need to add the JARs ourselves?

And also how do I know the dependencies to add in the `pom.xml?`

Comment: Have you read [Maven Getting Started Guide, How do I use external dependencies?](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_use_external_dependencies) and [Maven, Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) already?

Answer (score 4):

Just add this piece of XML inside your POM.xml. In this case its going to donwload the joda-time dependency and store it in your local repository.

You can find artifacts in the http://mvnrepository.com/. To get another library just change the groupId, artifactid and version.

```
<project>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

"Dependency" here means what *your* project depends on e.g., if you want to use Log4j in your project, then you depend on that library. When you add a dependency to the pom.xml, your IDE (Eclipse) will use Maven to download the jars and store them in your local repository (%HOME%/.m2 folder) so that you can compile your project and run it. Maven also allows manages transitive dependencies for you (libraries that your dependencies rely on).

If you are using maven as the build system then you can also configure it to create an "uber jar" when building your project which is a jar of your code and your dependency libraries together in one jar.

Comment: Re _"your IDE (Eclipse) will use Maven to download the jars"_ – To be precise: It's either the (embedded) [_M2Eclipse (m2e)_](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) plugin or the native Maven installation that downloads dependencies. If it is the latter Eclipse does nothing but invoking `mvn` with a given phase. _"You never have to worry about where to find those ..."_ isn't always true. Many, but not all libraries reside in the [Maven Central Repository](http://central.sonatype.org/).

Comment: You could adapt your answer accordingly and we could delete our comments afterwards.